# Converting encoded polylines into GeoJSON and KML files?

Tags: geojson, kml, convert, line, software-recommendations

There are plenty of resources available online to help users encode polylines. I am looking for something that does the opposite but my extensive research yields minimal results. I have a massive set of encoded polylines that I'd like to convert into geojson files, and eventually into kml files so I can import into qgis for further analysis. I'm not a coder (at all) so will not be able to complete this tasks using python or javascript.

An example of an encoded polyline:

```
_{reFxmjVpAeBn@{@w@aAc@m@yAsBJuAC}BIeAO_Ak@sBCQOg@g@aAk@}@qAwAs@s@}I{JgCqCsC_D}DeEyDgEsA}AwB{BcCwCoGyGqBwByEwFgHqHgDqDkIaJyFuGeEsEeEcEcGkGkEaFyDyDgBqBcAgAm@y@w@gAuCcCmFeHk@i@eAgAaDaDcC_CoBaCeBkCwAiCkCuFoPy]eAkCy@eC{@eDq@kDk@cEwAyQiBsVkAsN}Egn@q@sJ_@iGWgFg@mMcAuWQcCg@yFkBkRc@{EiAmKuBiT]sDWiEy@kPg@_Gg@_E{AuOkAgKo@gFe@oDq@oEe@qBmAeEWkAOaAKoAC}ADiBPeBFc@\wA~@oC@sAh@CVgBJoA@c@EWBkAAcBGgB[yC}AuNu@iHG}B@uBJcBJmAjEeZbAuGz@uFh@}DV]H[RkAfAqGJe@l@mBl@eAv@w@n@]TIj@Ml@In@?Df@n@Fh@@|H|AzDj@zDl@l@F^KhAZhCp@pAXnCr@bBh@nBbAfCdB|@z@vCfDPTjAvAhArAjBjBlBdBlEnC\TCzAtEpCtDtBrEdCdExB~DpBnAj@z@XdAPtBLr@CH?pAQZKfBs@t@e@x@s@|@cAt@mAh@gA@mAlAmEFELSpAyD|A_GfAeC|B}HT_At@gDjCaJZq@dB{F~AeFmCuAgCyAv@mCd@}AfA}C~@oBr@iA|BcDn@gA~@iBTo@~@qCh@gCXoB??P{AP_BU_@e@w@d@v@nArBl@v@ClBlBtAdATnAXLCFAXiALc@Ng@X}A^eCvB{T\qDZsBSeATmBr@mE?@ASVkAv@iDlBqHvA_FhAcDv@qBtBaFbIyQpBsDrAoBdAiAp@k@r@g@v@a@lAi@dBk@dG{AfD}@v@YzAq@|BsAfA{@[|A_BvAiBv@oAAiB@A@cAf@_BzBaJrM}j@x@eCz@mBbAgBlAeBhAmArAmAhCkB|MeJnD_CjByAxE}DtG{FlNsL~WaUjMmK|GyFjR}OdI_HhYcV~SoQfCwBnGeF~I}HbHcGnDyCDmCbJyHhA}@~FeF~GwFnNmLzCkCtJkJ|MeNDeDjGkGxGmGtAyApHcHrBiBlAsAdF_GRyZhI{MlJcPBeC~PaYdPaXjOqVbLcRdXmc@dDqFhLgRtGmKj@aAlB}Cz@oAR]tAeC~EqHtWwb@fRc[bDgGzB}Df@{@fIuLxGsKzBwCtCyCbB{AfAw@bC}AlGgDbEsBdIgEl@]fNkH~VcN~f@wWzP_Jr@c@zIeFAo@xEwCbHmEdGyDnIsF~MyIrJmGrUaOlSmMzDgC~k@e@bf@{Z~n@ca@|QqLtRcMdp@ab@naAkn@fBeADaBfDwANBJ?nAWhCm@^Gf@@XHZPp@f@xDfCpF}NpAcDpA_DjF}MtGyPLY]UyDkCoFqDaAC_@z@aApBoAzC]W??\Vt@iBd@gAdAuBNa@r@gBz@h@~B~AdBhAhChBZTLYnCeHtAmDnHgRjHcRtCqH~FcOvBuFdEyKpLoZvL_[v@mBjH}QXaAfAkCx@sBXaAlEwKpA}CfDgIx@mB^y@FE@Ap@uAfCaGrIsSA_CxAeDnGyOlFiMdBeECcGhG_O??AaCnDrC~DvCrNtKz_@~YfUfQtFhE~DD|@p@\Pn@RbATjBBpABzANv@ThAh@|@n@@^ZXf@p@NfA@t@KXSV_@LWA[KU]Ie@?WJk@Le@hA}CBK@g@bAwBlCkGzFoN~KqYpOk@zF_OzAaDfB_DpCmEzJwMfPqTT}XjLoOvJwMh@q@vK}NjEwFbDsErKiOvWi_@d\{d@V_@r@cA~@qAb@u@xB{CrIyLhIoLxKsOnG_JjB}Bp@u@fC_CxCyBnC{A|D}AfFuBrOeGG}Bfh@mShc@}PdIeDhG{BbE{AjD_AzDw@pFq@zJiA|@MxAKbNcBfJaAtOkBbKiA~TwCzFo@nC]bKaAhGm@~Hi@d@AbPaA~AOpCe@pEkAdA]zEkBj@UfB}@|Aw@xBs@|Ac@xJ_Cf@Dr@GrBa@fBYdBQvDQv@MlA]pG{BrAc@xCu@~Cm@zCg@|@WSqAOeA_@oDMqDT}`@JaC^qBZcAZw@xD}HvAsCpBiE~BkGJYg@c@eCaBO^i@tAc@dAo@~A
```

Is there an online converter somewhere that will help accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that the encoding format you are using is Google's [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). I was also not able to find a tool that converted directly from EPAF to GeoJSON, but I did find [a mapbox project on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/polyline) that provides the functionality in JavaScript. As you said you are not a coder, I wrapped the functionality into a JSFiddle for you so you can use this as an online tool - but be aware that if you want to do a lot of conversions you may want to use code to automate this.

You'll find the tool at https://jsfiddle.net/ivansams/tw7qLvh4/2/

Paste your code into "Encoded Polyline" and click "Decode". You should then be able to import the resulting GeoJSON into QGis and take it from there! Your example encoded polyline returns the following linestring:

```
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-3.82701,37.78496],[-3.8265,37.78455],[-3.8262,37.78431],[-3.82587,37.78459],[-3.82564,37.78477],[-3.82506,37.78522],[-3.82463,37.78516],[-3.824,37.78518],[-3.82365,37.78523],[-3.82333,37.78531],[-3.82275,37.78553],[-3.82266,37.78555],[-3.82246,37.78563],[-3.82213,37.78583],[-3.82182,37.78605],[-3.82138,37.78646],[-3.82112,37.78672],[-3.81922,37.78847],[-3.81849,37.78915],[-3.81769,37.78989],[-3.8167,37.79084],[-3.8157,37.79177],[-3.81523,37.79219],[-3.81461,37.79279],[-3.81385,37.79345],[-3.81244,37.79481],[-3.81184,37.79538],[-3.8106,37.79647],[-3.80907,37.79795],[-3.80818,37.79879],[-3.80641,37.80045],[-3.80502,37.8017],[-3.80396,37.80269],[-3.80298,37.80368],[-3.80164,37.80498],[-3.80051,37.806],[-3.79958,37.80693],[-3.79901,37.80745],[-3.79865,37.80779],[-3.79836,37.80802],[-3.798,37.8083],[-3.79734,37.80905],[-3.79587,37.81024],[-3.79566,37.81046],[-3.7953,37.81081],[-3.79449,37.81162],[-3.79385,37.81228],[-3.7932,37.81284],[-3.7925,37.81335],[-3.79181,37.81379],[-3.79058,37.81449],[-3.78565,37.81729],[-3.78495,37.81764],[-3.78428,37.81793],[-3.78345,37.81823],[-3.78259,37.81848],[-3.78161,37.8187],[-3.7786,37.81914],[-3.77482,37.81967],[-3.77232,37.82005],[-3.76476,37.82116],[-3.7629,37.82141],[-3.76157,37.82157],[-3.76041,37.82169],[-3.7581,37.82189],[-3.75415,37.82223],[-3.75349,37.82232],[-3.75224,37.82252],[-3.74914,37.82306],[-3.74804,37.82324],[-3.74605,37.82361],[-3.74264,37.8242],[-3.74174,37.82435],[-3.74073,37.82447],[-3.73795,37.82476],[-3.73667,37.82496],[-3.73571,37.82516],[-3.73304,37.82562],[-3.73108,37.826],[-3.72992,37.82624],[-3.72904,37.82643],[-3.728,37.82668],[-3.72743,37.82687],[-3.72644,37.82726],[-3.72606,37.82738],[-3.72573,37.82746],[-3.72533,37.82752],[-3.72486,37.82754],[-3.72433,37.82751],[-3.72382,37.82742],[-3.72364,37.82738],[-3.7232,37.82723],[-3.72248,37.82691],[-3.72206,37.8269],[-3.72204,37.82669],[-3.72152,37.82657],[-3.72112,37.82651],[-3.72094,37.8265],[-3.72082,37.82653],[-3.72044,37.82651],[-3.71994,37.82652],[-3.71942,37.82656],[-3.71865,37.8267],[-3.71614,37.82717],[-3.71465,37.82744],[-3.71402,37.82748],[-3.71343,37.82747],[-3.71293,37.82741],[-3.71254,37.82735],[-3.70819,37.82633],[-3.7068,37.82599],[-3.70557,37.82569],[-3.70462,37.82548],[-3.70447,37.82536],[-3.70433,37.82531],[-3.70395,37.82521],[-3.70258,37.82485],[-3.70239,37.82479],[-3.70184,37.82456],[-3.70149,37.82433],[-3.70121,37.82405],[-3.70106,37.82381],[-3.70101,37.8237],[-3.70094,37.82348],[-3.70089,37.82325],[-3.70089,37.82301],[-3.70109,37.82298],[-3.70113,37.82274],[-3.70114,37.82253],[-3.70161,37.82094],[-3.70183,37.82],[-3.70206,37.81906],[-3.7021,37.81883],[-3.70204,37.81867],[-3.70218,37.8183],[-3.70243,37.81761],[-3.70256,37.8172],[-3.70282,37.81648],[-3.70303,37.81598],[-3.70337,37.81542],[-3.70388,37.81474],[-3.70418,37.81443],[-3.70502,37.81367],[-3.70513,37.81358],[-3.70557,37.8132],[-3.70599,37.81283],[-3.70653,37.81229],[-3.70704,37.81174],[-3.70776,37.81071],[-3.70787,37.81056],[-3.70833,37.81058],[-3.70906,37.80951],[-3.70965,37.8086],[-3.71032,37.80754],[-3.71093,37.80655],[-3.7115,37.80559],[-3.71172,37.80519],[-3.71185,37.80489],[-3.71194,37.80454],[-3.71201,37.80395],[-3.71199,37.80369],[-3.71199,37.80364],[-3.7119,37.80323],[-3.71184,37.80309],[-3.71158,37.80257],[-3.71139,37.8023],[-3.71113,37.80201],[-3.71079,37.8017],[-3.7104,37.80143],[-3.71004,37.80122],[-3.70965,37.80121],[-3.70862,37.80082],[-3.70859,37.80078],[-3.70849,37.80071],[-3.70756,37.8003],[-3.70628,37.79983],[-3.70561,37.79947],[-3.70402,37.79884],[-3.7037,37.79873],[-3.70286,37.79846],[-3.70109,37.79776],[-3.70084,37.79762],[-3.69958,37.79711],[-3.69843,37.79663],[-3.698,37.79734],[-3.69755,37.79802],[-3.69684,37.79774],[-3.69637,37.79755],[-3.69558,37.79719],[-3.69502,37.79687],[-3.69465,37.79661],[-3.69383,37.79598],[-3.69347,37.79574],[-3.69294,37.79542],[-3.6927,37.79531],[-3.69197,37.79499],[-3.69129,37.79478],[-3.69073,37.79465],[-3.69073,37.79465],[-3.69027,37.79456],[-3.68979,37.79447],[-3.68963,37.79458],[-3.68935,37.79477],[-3.68963,37.79458],[-3.69021,37.79418],[-3.69049,37.79395],[-3.69104,37.79397],[-3.69147,37.79342],[-3.69158,37.79307],[-3.69171,37.79267],[-3.69169,37.7926],[-3.69168,37.79256],[-3.69131,37.79243],[-3.69113,37.79236],[-3.69093,37.79228],[-3.69046,37.79215],[-3.68979,37.79199],[-3.68629,37.79139],[-3.6854,37.79124],[-3.68482,37.7911],[-3.68447,37.7912],[-3.68392,37.79109],[-3.68289,37.79083],[-3.6829,37.79083],[-3.6828,37.79084],[-3.68242,37.79072],[-3.68157,37.79044],[-3.68004,37.78989],[-3.67892,37.78945],[-3.6781,37.78908],[-3.67753,37.7888],[-3.6764,37.78821],[-3.67339,37.78659],[-3.67249,37.78602],[-3.67193,37.7856],[-3.67156,37.78525],[-3.67134,37.785],[-3.67114,37.78474],[-3.67097,37.78446],[-3.67076,37.78407],[-3.67054,37.78356],[-3.67008,37.78225],[-3.66977,37.78141],[-3.66964,37.78113],[-3.66939,37.78067],[-3.66897,37.78004],[-3.66867,37.77968],[-3.66914,37.77982],[-3.66958,37.7803],[-3.66986,37.78083],[-3.66985,37.78123],[-3.66986,37.78176],[-3.66987,37.78177],[-3.67007,37.78211],[-3.67069,37.78259],[-3.67303,37.78436],[-3.67332,37.79139],[-3.67362,37.79206],[-3.67396,37.79261],[-3.67435,37.79313],[-3.67472,37.79364],[-3.67514,37.79403],[-3.67583,37.79442],[-3.67822,37.79496],[-3.6791,37.79675],[-3.67964,37.79739],[-3.68073,37.79784],[-3.68212,37.79879],[-3.68459,37.80005],[-3.68859,37.80223],[-3.69089,37.80576],[-3.69232,37.80775],[-3.69542,37.809],[-3.69705,37.81171],[-3.70126,37.81315],[-3.70462,37.81685],[-3.7053,37.81981],[-3.70666,37.82041],[-3.70842,37.82156],[-3.70988,37.82315],[-3.71076,37.82445],[-3.71079,37.82522],[-3.71257,37.82593],[-3.71294,37.8275],[-3.71422,37.82781],[-3.71566,37.82896],[-3.71814,37.8302],[-3.71892,37.83235],[-3.72079,37.83305],[-3.72318,37.83487],[-3.72321,37.8373],[-3.72455,37.83813],[-3.72596,37.83947],[-3.72639,37.84082],[-3.72792,37.84127],[-3.7285,37.84273],[-3.72889,37.84326],[-3.73004,37.84368],[-3.73014,37.84496],[-3.73179,37.84941],[-3.73362,37.85179],[-3.73364,37.85453],[-3.73652,37.8552],[-3.73927,37.85937],[-3.74189,37.86338],[-3.74399,37.86715],[-3.74802,37.87021],[-3.74885,37.87604],[-3.75098,37.87725],[-3.75237,37.88033],[-3.75259,37.88232],[-3.75314,37.88265],[-3.75344,37.88344],[-3.75354,37.88384],[-3.75397,37.88399],[-3.75509,37.88466],[-3.75904,37.88619],[-3.76212,37.89191],[-3.76294,37.89641],[-3.76356,37.89773],[-3.76376,37.89868],[-3.7654,37.89898],[-3.76681,37.90117],[-3.76743,37.90319],[-3.76818,37.90395],[-3.76868,37.90472],[-3.76904,37.90518],[-3.7697,37.90546],[-3.77105,37.90593],[-3.77203,37.90677],[-3.77366,37.90735],[-3.77389,37.90835],[-3.77633,37.9085],[-3.78017,37.91],[-3.78657,37.91242],[-3.78943,37.91638],[-3.78969,37.91814],[-3.79143,37.91832],[-3.79142,37.91947],[-3.79251,37.91971],[-3.79397,37.92047],[-3.79528,37.9215],[-3.79696,37.92243],[-3.79936,37.92365],[-3.80122,37.92538],[-3.80484,37.92673],[-3.80811,37.9293],[-3.80905,37.93161],[-3.81625,37.93229],[-3.82251,37.93248],[-3.83019,37.93694],[-3.83322,37.9424],[-3.83637,37.94457],[-3.84424,37.94683],[-3.85488,37.95244],[-3.8554,37.96002],[-3.85543,37.96037],[-3.85627,37.96086],[-3.85635,37.9613],[-3.85641,37.96128],[-3.85681,37.96128],[-3.8575,37.9614],[-3.85766,37.96163],[-3.85786,37.96167],[-3.85799,37.96166],[-3.85813,37.96161],[-3.85838,37.96152],[-3.85931,37.96132],[-3.86052,37.96064],[-3.86093,37.96319],[-3.86134,37.96401],[-3.86252,37.96481],[-3.86391,37.9672],[-3.86398,37.97005],[-3.86383,37.97018],[-3.8629,37.97029],[-3.8617,37.97099],[-3.86137,37.97188],[-3.86121,37.9719],[-3.86088,37.9716],[-3.86048,37.97103],[-3.86033,37.97025],[-3.86033,37.97037],[-3.86048,37.97037],[-3.86075,37.97025],[-3.86094,37.97078],[-3.86129,37.97114],[-3.86137,37.97173],[-3.86163,37.9719],[-3.86193,37.97242],[-3.86257,37.97221],[-3.86308,37.97173],[-3.86377,37.97136],[-3.86391,37.97083],[-3.86398,37.97072],[-3.8647,37.97085],[-3.86513,37.97232],[-3.86665,37.97319],[-3.86815,37.97627],[-3.8689,37.97933],[-3.87018,37.98086],[-3.87078,37.98344],[-3.87177,37.98467],[-3.87394,37.98672],[-3.87614,37.99112],[-3.87642,37.9956],[-3.87792,37.99615],[-3.87805,37.99918],[-3.87841,37.99951],[-3.8787,38.00021],[-3.87883,38.00079],[-3.87986,38.00112],[-3.88027,38.00316],[-3.88111,38.00395],[-3.8814,38.00559],[-3.88156,38.00614],[-3.8816,38.00643],[-3.88161,38.00646],[-3.88186,38.00647],[-3.88254,38.0069],[-3.88424,38.00819],[-3.88423,38.01149],[-3.88468,38.01213],[-3.88604,38.01296],[-3.88723,38.01565],[-3.88774,38.01794],[-3.88772,38.01893],[-3.88905,38.02023],[-3.88905,38.02279],[-3.88904,38.02279],[-3.88992,38.02344],[-3.89088,38.0227],[-3.89338,38.02194],[-3.89864,38.01991],[-3.9022,38.01559],[-3.90343,38.01267],[-3.90439,38.01166],[-3.9047,38.01163],[-3.90485,38.01138],[-3.90509,38.01129],[-3.90543,38.01119],[-3.90597,38.01108],[-3.90638,38.01106],[-3.90684,38.01104],[-3.90712,38.01096],[-3.90749,38.01085],[-3.9078,38.01064],[-3.90781,38.0104],[-3.90795,38.01024],[-3.90815,38.01011],[-3.90823,38.00986],[-3.90824,38.0095],[-3.90818,38.00923],[-3.90808,38.0091],[-3.90792,38.00898],[-3.9078,38.00891],[-3.90766,38.00892],[-3.90755,38.00898],[-3.9075,38.00913],[-3.9075,38.00932],[-3.90756,38.00944],[-3.90763,38.00966],[-3.908,38.00985],[-3.90802,38.01064],[-3.90803,38.0107],[-3.90837,38.0109],[-3.90908,38.0115],[-3.91034,38.01284],[-3.91242,38.01532],[-3.91507,38.01957],[-3.91633,38.01979],[-3.91679,38.02235],[-3.91731,38.02316],[-3.91804,38.02396],[-3.91994,38.02499],[-3.9227,38.02735],[-3.92281,38.0308],[-3.92495,38.03495],[-3.92683,38.03759],[-3.92704,38.03995],[-3.92908,38.0402],[-3.9301,38.04275],[-3.93092,38.04399],[-3.93294,38.04505],[-3.9369,38.04766],[-4.13085,38.05283],[-4.13069,38.05271],[-4.13035,38.05245],[-4.12994,38.05213],[-4.12967,38.05195],[-4.12889,38.05134],[-4.12668,38.04964],[-4.12452,38.04799],[-4.12186,38.04594],[-4.1201,38.04458],[-4.11947,38.04404],[-4.1192,38.04379],[-4.11856,38.04311],[-4.11795,38.04234],[-4.11749,38.04162],[-4.11702,38.04067],[-4.11643,38.03951],[-4.11512,38.03685],[-4.11449,38.03689],[-4.11122,38.03029],[-4.10835,38.02448],[-4.10752,38.02285],[-4.1069,38.02152],[-4.10644,38.02054],[-4.10612,38.01968],[-4.10584,38.01874],[-4.10559,38.01753],[-4.10522,38.01563],[-4.10515,38.01532],[-4.10509,38.01487],[-4.10459,38.01245],[-4.10426,38.01065],[-4.10372,38.00798],[-4.10335,38.00604],[-4.10259,38.00252],[-4.10235,38.00126],[-4.1022,38.00054],[-4.10187,37.9986],[-4.10164,37.99727],[-4.10143,37.99567],[-4.10142,37.99548],[-4.10109,37.99274],[-4.10101,37.99226],[-4.10082,37.99153],[-4.10044,37.99048],[-4.10029,37.99013],[-4.09975,37.98903],[-4.09964,37.98881],[-4.09933,37.98829],[-4.09905,37.98782],[-4.09879,37.98721],[-4.09861,37.98674],[-4.09797,37.98485],[-4.098,37.98465],[-4.09796,37.98439],[-4.09779,37.98381],[-4.09766,37.98329],[-4.09757,37.98278],[-4.09748,37.98186],[-4.09741,37.98158],[-4.09726,37.98119],[-4.09664,37.97982],[-4.09646,37.9794],[-4.09619,37.97863],[-4.09596,37.97783],[-4.09576,37.97705],[-4.09564,37.97674],[-4.09523,37.97684],[-4.09488,37.97692],[-4.094,37.97708],[-4.09311,37.97715],[-4.08768,37.97704],[-4.08703,37.97698],[-4.08646,37.97682],[-4.08612,37.97668],[-4.08584,37.97654],[-4.08425,37.97561],[-4.08351,37.97517],[-4.0825,37.9746],[-4.08116,37.97396],[-4.08103,37.9739],[-4.08085,37.9741],[-4.08036,37.97477],[-4.08052,37.97485],[-4.08095,37.97506],[-4.0813,37.97524],[-4.08178,37.97548]]}
```